# Error al ejecutar mi Backup en el crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab

necesito ayuda, necesito crear una tarea crontab desde ubuntu para sacar un backup a mi BD que la tengo en un hosting compartido, al ejecutar la tarea:

```
mysqldump -hsub.dominio.com -uusuario -pmipass midb > /home/usuario/Escritorio/Backups/midb date+%D.sql
```

me aparece lo siguiente:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.25, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: sub.dominio.com    Database: midb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.5-10.4.17-MariaDB-cll-lve

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

lo que logro entender es que comienza a hacerlo, pero no veo si tengo algún error para que no continue

Comment: Será que ese nombre de archivo con espacios genera líos? Será que no tienes permisos para escribir ahí? Ese comando lo ejecutaste en consola o ya en un crontab? Porque la tarea no la va a ejecutar tu usuario necesariamente, lo que complica los permisos en la carpeta de `usuario`...

Comment: @Alfabravo pues le di un chmod 777 a la carpeta, pero voy a ver con respecto del espacio

Comment: encontré este post https://www.tecno-tips.com/linux/mysql/automatizar-backups-de-mysql-utilizando-crontab-y-linux/ y a pesar de que ya está probado me da el mismo problema, solo empieza y se queda exactamente donde está mi ejemplo

Comment: ¿Dónde esta la llamada a `mysqldump`? ¿En crontab o en un shell script?

Answer (score -1):

En teoría veo que tu **script** está bien. Tal vez, haga falta asignarle permisos de ejecución, eso lo haces así:

```sh
chmod +x mysqldump.sh
```

Para el `date` te recomiendo hacerlo así:

```
backup_path="/path/a/tu/destino/_backup/mysql"
date=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")

mysqldump --user=tuUsuario --password=tuPassword --host=localhost dbName > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql
```

Espero te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: ya lo probé local "mysqldump -u root -p midb > backup.sql" pero me aparece este error: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect estuve viendo y pues me tocó crear este archivo en este directorio pero a pesar de seguir estas instrucciones: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysql" el problema persiste

Comment: @MauEspaña mysqld.sock no es un archivo que debas crear. Es un archivo que se crea al establecer la conexión con la BD. ese usuario sí se puede conectar usando esa contraseña, a esa BD?

Comment: si se puede conectar, ya que tengo una conexion creada con workbench, pero me da este error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) y no hayo como solucionarlo todavía